# Java MultiThreading - One thread enters critical section twice before other thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a critical code, wrapped inside `synchronized (this) {}`.

In the logs I see thread #1 enters critical section, then thread #2 reaches there, and waits, then, Thread #1 leaves critical section, and enters it again (2ms later) ! even before the other thread entered.

How is it possible ?
didn't thread #2 should have entered the critical section ?

**EDIT:**

adding part of my class...

```
@Service
public class RequestService {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestService.class);

    public HttpResponse executeRequest(HttpClient httpClient, HttpGet request) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        logger.info("About to enter critical code");
        synchronized (this) {
            logger.info("executing http request");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            logger.info("got http response");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show more of your code.  Are your threads operating on different instances of a class?  Then `this` is different in different threads, and can be locked independently.

Comment: I imagine it's a problem with your code.

Comment: @rgettman - same class. Spring singleton service.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - that's comforting, I think. attaching my code.

Comment: It's possible because the Java language spec does not say that it's _impossible_.  There's no guarantee that thread #2 will "wake up" before thread #1 comes 'round and reaches the synchronized block again, and there's no guarantee that threads will acquire the lock in the same order that they attempted it (i.e., Java `synchronized` blocks are not _fair_.)

Comment: It's clearly *much* more efficient to keep each thread running as long as possible and allow threads that don't contend to run concurrently than to try to keep switching between threads over and over to maximize contention.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, generally true, but 2ms is larger a long time. I would not expect them to be fair as a judge, but i would expect that someone will have it's chance in 2ms time frame.

Comment: @SergeyA It makes more sense to allow a thread to keep acquiring a lock so long as it can't make significant progress without it until it uses up its timeslice. If two threads more or less 100% contend, and that's the case here (inside the `synchronized` block 99% of the time, and only outside it for negligible periods at a time), the best thing you can do is to let each thread use up its timeslice. It's not fair to either thread to allow the other thread to make it so horribly inefficient. Each switch can blow out caches, which is painful.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, like I said - do not argue in prinicple. It is just that 2ms seems rather long time to me.

Comment: @SergeyA On modern CPUs, switching contexts every 2ms would be about a 3% reduction in throughput. But here, the code spends much less than 2ms outside the `synchronized` block. And time spent inside the `synchronzed` block is irrelevant -- you *can't* switch then, and the currently running thread should get to finish its timeslice -- that's what timeslices are for.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, yeah, you are probably right. It just seems like long time - I mean, without actually calculating, simply feels long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) if you want to introduce fairness,

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
```

Threads waiting to enter the critical section will enter in a "fair" order, in the order they were queued.

The default fairness policy is "unfair" because fairness comes with a performance overhead that most applications don't need.

Answer (score 5):

synchronized blocks are not "fair". There's no guarantee which thread will be able to enter a synchronized block when it becomes available.

Comment: but I guess thread #2 got some cpu after thread #1 left the critical section. and before it entered it again, why didn't enter the critical section ?

Comment: You're asking why Java doesn't maximize contention. It's because contention is bad. We want to get as much work as possible done without switching threads so we get more work done for the same number of thread switches. Alternation is clearly the worst possible scenario. If you have to pick up 5 things at one store and 5 things at another store, do you pick up 1 thing from the first store and then go to the other?

Comment: @Nati - whether or not #2 got some cpu (unsure how you are determining that), doesn't change my answer.  the jvm could perfectly well deny thread #2 for 15 minutes just because it doesn't like it.

Comment: @jtahlborn, JVm is a program which works how it is programmed to. _just because it doesn't like it_ is not a fair argument. I think OP wants to know what's the logic JVM follows to pickup threads and in what situation it will pickup same thread again

Comment: @CharuKhurana - i'm using hyperbole to make a point: the java spec doesn't guarantee fairness for synchronized blocks, therefore the jvm is free to handle choosing however it likes.  the jvm isn't _a_ program, it is actually _many_ programs implemented by multiple vendors which (hopefully) adhere to the spec.  there is no way to specify the logic because each jvm has different logic.  the _only_ thing you can point to is the spec.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jtahlborn